# Docker Xdebug Apache MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, xdebug

I am trying to install my project in a Docker. Everything works good except for Xdebug which does not want to stop on breakpoints. I am using the latest version of Docker, macOS, Xdebug. PHP 7.1, Apache 2.4.

Here are settings I've got:

I added these lines to php.ini

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=PHP_STORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

[image: phpinfo]

I can see in phpinfo that Xdebug is enabled.

I can validate Xdebug in PhpStorm:

[image: validate Xdebug]

And here are settings in my PhpStorm:

[image: Xdebug port listening]

[image: debug configuration]

[image: server configuration]

Ports in docker-compose file are only set `8888:80`

Could you please advice, am I missing something?

P.S. if I try to install Xdebug locally, it works fine. But I need it to be working with Docker.

Comment: First of all: collect and check Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect etc. Then you can start looking at other stuff.

Comment: What is the value of the xdebug.remote_handler setting in phpinfo()?

Answer (score 0):

Which version if php-debug ? There is a bug in 2.9.1 that cause a segmentation fault when xdebug.remote_enable=1 (see https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/544)

Comment: That bug is only relevant if you have other *strange* third party extensions loaded. And it's fixed in 2.9.2 which I released yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a long response. I just disabled my laptop that evening, enabled it next day and everything started worked.Really weird thing. But thanks for advises.